# Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::beforeFilter()

Tags: php, laravel

Am trying to restrict access to my account page in Laravel but keep getting the above message.

Code:

```
use Illuminate\Auth\UserTrait;
use Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableTrait;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableInterface;

    class User extends BaseModel implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface {

    public function __construct() {
        $this->beforeFilter('auth', array('only'=>array('viewAccount')));
        $this->beforeFilter('csrf', array('on'=>'post'));
    }
}
```

Comment: the error says exactly what it is. the compiler cannot find the method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `beforeFilter` method should be called in your controller's constructor, not the model.